# Xml parser doesn't work

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response list="true">
  <audio>
    <aid>253663595</aid>
    <artist>Example</artist>
    <duration>389</duration>
    <lyrics_id>57485771</lyrics_id>
    <genre>18</genre>
  </audio>
  <audio>
    <aid>253663595</aid>
    <artist>Example1</artist>
    <duration>400</duration>
    <lyrics_id>57485772</lyrics_id>
    <genre>20</genre>
  </audio>
</response>
```

Source code

```
XmlDocument allAudio = new XmlDocument();
                     allAudio.Load(@"e:\Audio.xml");
                     StreamWriter write_text = File.CreateText(@"e:\Audio.txt");
                     XmlNodeList audioNodes = allAudio.GetElementsByTagName("audio");
                     foreach (XmlNode audioNode in audioNodes)
                     {
                         XmlNode artistNode = audioNode["artist"];
                         write_text.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", artistNode.Value));
                     }
                     write_text.Close();
```

Hi, I can't parse xml. I want write some node values in file, but as result I get an empty txt file.

Comment: What programming language is the second block meant to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:  `artistNode.InnerText`

Not: `artistNode.value`